# "ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement kivy_deps.sdl2_dev~=0.4.5 (from versions: 0.5.1)" shows up trying to install kivy

Tags: python, pip, kivy, virtualenv, command-prompt

When I try to install Kivy on Python it all runs fine at first, before the message in the title shows up.

```
C:\Users\finnj>pip install kivy
Collecting kivy
  Using cached Kivy-2.1.0.tar.gz (23.8 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [10 lines of output]
      Collecting setuptools
        Using cached setuptools-65.6.3-py3-none-any.whl (1.2 MB)
      Collecting wheel
        Using cached wheel-0.38.4-py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
      Collecting cython!=0.27,!=0.27.2,<=0.29.28,>=0.24
        Using cached Cython-0.29.28-py2.py3-none-any.whl (983 kB)
      Collecting kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev~=0.3.3
        Using cached kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev-0.3.3-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (3.9 MB)
      ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement kivy_deps.sdl2_dev~=0.4.5 (from versions: 0.5.1)
      ERROR: No matching distribution found for kivy_deps.sdl2_dev~=0.4.5
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I tried installing "cython" because it helped in some similar problems, however it did not change at all.

My version is 3.11.

Comment: Kivy only supports up through Python version 3.10.   A better install command would be python3 -m pip install kivy.  You can first verify which python version you have just with the command python3 and then use exit() to close it.

Answer (score 3):

you need to install it with command

pip install git+https://github.com/kivy/kivy

i have same with that problem, but i install it from github and its work

Answer (score 1):

run cmd

pip install kivy[base] kivy_examples --pre --extra-index-url https://kivy.org/downloads/simple/