# I faced this problem while installing kivy in pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, kivy, dotenv

```
Collecting kivy
  Using cached Kivy-2.1.0.tar.gz (23.8 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [10 lines of output]
      Collecting setuptools
        Using cached setuptools-67.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
      Collecting wheel
        Using cached wheel-0.38.4-py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
      Collecting cython!=0.27,!=0.27.2,<=0.29.28,>=0.24
        Using cached Cython-0.29.28-py2.py3-none-any.whl (983 kB)
      Collecting kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev~=0.3.3
        Using cached kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev-0.3.3-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (3.9 MB)
      ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement kivy_deps.sdl2_dev~=0.4.5 (from versions: 0.5.1)
      ERROR: No matching distribution found for kivy_deps.sdl2_dev~=0.4.5
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I wrote (py -m pip install kivy) and it give me this error and even when I want to install dotenv it give the same error

Comment: When I typed "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement kivy_deps" into the internet search engine, the first hit was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75085186/error-could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-kivy-deps-sdl2-d). Does it help?

Answer (score 0):

Use this command the problem will be solved:
python -m pip install "kivy[base]" --pre --extra-index-url https://kivy.org/downloads/simple/